# ImportError: DLL load failed for tf, win8.1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to detect objects using Tensorflow. I'm using a CPU, not a GPU.
Features Intel Celeron processor, no video card- Hd graphics, Win8.1.
I know the specs are low but after a few steps I will be using Colab. Python 3.7 and tensorflow 2.3 version installed. The error I get when I want to import Tensorflow :

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Devingen bağlantı kitaplığını (DLL) başlatma işlem
i başarısız.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I also get this problem in other detections.I am working from the cmd screen. Whatever I did didn't happen not working. Please help :/

All Code:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\eycan>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD6
4)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Devingen bağlantı kitaplığını (DLL) başlatma işlem
i başarısız.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <mod
ule>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in
<module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __get
attr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load

    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line
49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Devingen bağlantı kitaplığını (DLL) başlatma işlem
i başarısız.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Comment: Tensorflow is supported only on the 64-bit systems. You can refer [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) and [build and install error messages](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors). Hope these reference will help you. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install MSVC 2019? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows